# Lack of non-normalized 10_10_10_2 vertex format in Metal

Tags: metal, metalkit

In my OpenGL ES 3.0+ apps I use non-normalized `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` data types which is perfectly fine according to specs - https://docs.gl/es3/glVertexAttribPointer

When porting to Metal I've found that it does support `10_10_10_2` data type for vertex attributes but only as normalized ones - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlvertexformat

iOS 12 used to support OpenGL ES 3.0 which means hardware is perfectly capable of handling both normalized and non-normalized `10_10_10_2` data types.

Am I missing something or is this indeed an artificial limitation by Apple?
Metal doesn't provide additional flag for normalized attribute so it indeed seems like they just "forgot" that `10_10_10_2` could be useful as non-normalized too... I know this is not quite typical usage for this data type but precision is good enough for my use case and it is more compact than 3 half floats.

Currently I see two workarounds to alleviate this:

1. De-normalize data in vertex shader with multiplication by 512.
2. Re-export meshes to use half floats instead of this more compact packed data type.

Please advise.

Comment: You use pull interpolation, basically just taking the data in the vertex shader from the buffers and doing what you need to do with it instead of relying on `MTLVertexDescriptor`.

Comment: @Spo1ler yes this is basically my workaround #1. However, normalized variants of other formats do exist which makes me wonder why only 10_10_10_2 is present only as normalized one. I suppose normalized data types are there not just for convenience but for performance reasons too - they could be normalized for free by hardware and therefore being faster than doing additional math in shader (even as simple as one multiplication).

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, the format is not there so you have to do it some other way, unfortunately.

Comment: @Spo1ler OK you can answer my question then, I will accept it. Haven't found any confirmations for non-normalized 1010102 to be available in Metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatenyl, I don't think there's a version of `MTLVertexFormatUInt1010102Normalized` or `MTLVertexFormatInt1010102Normalized` that is not normalized.

What you could do instead is write a vertex shader manually that reads a 32-bit value from the buffer and decomposes into the same non-normalized 10-bit components with another one being 2-bit using regular bitwise functions.

More unfortunately, there isn't even a version of the `pack`/`unpack` functions such as `unpack_unorm10a2_to_half` that accepts or outputs non-normalized values.